# push one branch in one repo and push two branches to another in git?

Tags: git, branch

Short: is it possible to push the branch `public` to two repos and branch `private` in another **automatically** when I run `git push`?

Comment: No. But you can simply write an alias to do this.

Comment: You can accomplish this by writing a script.

Comment: But how can assure that one repo has only one branch?